# Sentences structures, grammar

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused about the examples below:

a) State of Florida vs Florida State
b) Department of transportation vs transportation department
c) ego state vs state of ego

What are correct? Does each line have the same meaning whether I use either the first or second example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a) It depends. When people say "Florida State", it's usually short for "Florida State University", so it's not the same as "State of Florida". On the other hand, "New York State" and "State of New York" can be used interchangeably. When in doubt, say "State of X", I'm pretty sure that's correct and unambiguous for all states (except Massachusetts, which is officially the "Commonwealth of Massachusetts").

b) "Department of transportation" and "transportation department" are usually equivalent. This also applies to "division", "ministry", "office", "bureau", etc. But it depends on the particular organization - for many of them, only one name is traditionally used. You wouldn't say that J. Edgar Hoover was head of the "Federal Investigation Bureau".

So in other words, sometimes both forms are acceptable, sometimes only one is acceptable, and there is no consistent rule - it depends on the specific thing you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

It's often the difference between something specific (proper noun) and something general.

(1) When you reference the Transportation Department (capitalized), you're referring to a specific transportation department (not capitalized). For example:

> Bob is the head of the New York Transportation Department.  (specific)
>
> Bob is trying to get a job at a transportation department.    (general)

(2) The Florida example is a little more complex because, as Mike Baranczak pointed out, **Florida State** is also short for *Florida State University*. Excluding that usage, however, I think is the same issue. For example:

> The committee met with the head of the Florida State Commission on Sunshine. (specific)
>
> There's a new State of Florida commission that's focused on sunshine. (general)